# How find people with two specific licenses, separate rows, only one with limited permit

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to put together a query so I can find people in our db that have both a NY permit/license and also a limited permit/license, but the rows are separate rows in the query.  I only want the ones without NYS license, where they are limited.

This is what I have so far:

```
p.Last_Name
,p.First_Name
,p.Middle_Initial
,p.person_id
,i.Document
,i.Expiration_date
,i.Updated_Date
--,i.IssueDate
--,i.Historical
--,i.Comments
--,f.Current_status
,i.State 

from dbo.PersonDoc_ID_Numbers i

inner join "DB"."dbo"."People" p on p.person_id = i.person_id
inner  join person_facilities f on p.person_id = f.person_id

where
(Document like '%limited%' and i.State like '%NY%' and ((i.Expiration_date > getdate()) or (i.Expiration_date is null))) or 
(Document like '%NY%' and i.State like '%NY%' and ((i.Expiration_date > getdate()) or (i.Expiration_date is null)))
and f.current_status in ('Active') 
and i.Historical != 1

order by p.Last_Name
```

So that's returning like this for someone, but I don't want the ones with NY license as well as limited; I just want ones with limited without NY license:

```
Last_Name   First_Name  Middle_Initial  person_id   Document           Expiration_date  Updated_Date
    GG       FF         L.          123             Limited Permit     2019-09-23       2018-10-04 456  
    GG       FF         L.          123             NY State License       NULL           2018-11-13 
    Smith        Tony   L.          456             Limited Permit     2019-09-23       2018-10-04 456  
    Snoopy       Dog    L.          789             NY State License       NULL           2018-11-13
```

So for FF GG, I wouldn't be interested in her name being returned because she has ny license, and the limited. I only want ones with just limited.  But I would expect it to return Tony Smith and that's it.

```
*Update as requested:
dbo.PersonDoc_ID_Numbers
person_id Expiration_date State  license_NO  Updated_Date  Historical  Document
1         2019-9-22        NY      2       2018-10-04     0       Limited Perm *
1         null             NY      no          2019-4-17    0         NY State
2         null             NY      3        2011-06-30    0         Limited Lic
2         null             NY      4         2011-06-14    0         NY State
3         2018-5-04        NY     5          2018-05-01    0        Limited Perm*
4         2019-08-29       NY      6         2018-01-12    0       Limited Lic *
5         null             null    7         2016-4-20     0        Jujufication
5         null             NY      8         2018-4-05     0         NY State  
6         2016-07-15       OH      9         2018-01-09    0         Snoopyism

dbo.Person_Facilities
person_id Current_status 
1         Active                    
2         Active                        
3         Active        
4         Active                   
5         Active              
6         Active      

dbo.Person
person_id First          Last  
1         GG             FF          
2         MM             PP        
3         Tony           Smith   
4         Snoopy         Dog      
5         Sarah          Gd           
6         Bethany        Yoda
```

I put an * next to the ones in the id table where they are expected to be in the end set. Note that it turns out FF GG doesn't have a license number so she needs to be in the end set.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and an example of what you want? It sounds like you're saying you want people with only a limited licence, and not any other kind of licence. It's hard to tell because your example is incomplete - where does personId get selected?? My initial thought here would be add row number to your select statement using something like `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY personId) as row_number` then select entries with only one row.

Comment: I added a couple more people.  It would return Tony Smith but not any other ones because Tony is the only one with just the Limited Document.

Comment: I fixed the question so it has person_id and removed columns from query that I didn't show in result.

Comment: I forgot to change the person_id's for the people I just added, so I fixed that.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your code is doint, but your condition in `WHERE` clause `and f.current_status in ('Active')` will definitely turn your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Eric - I changed the second one to inner join.  Good point.

Comment: @Eric - the number of rows returned is the same though with the join change. That'd be great if you had an answer on how to just return Tony.

Comment: So what happen if you remove `or 
(Document like '%NY%' and i.State like '%NY%' and ((i.Expiration_date > getdate()) or (i.Expiration_date is null))` from your `WHERE`?

Comment: Then my results contain FF GG limited, and Tony Smith limited.  But I don't want FF GG limited in there because she also has the nys license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your current query is all fine, you could use `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY p.person_id) AS noOfRows` to determine how many rows the query will generate, then `select` only the entries with a single row with a query along these lines:

```
WITH myCte AS (
    SELECT
    p.Last_Name
    ,p.First_Name
    ,p.Middle_Initial
    ,p.person_id
    ,i.Document
    ,i.Expiration_date
    ,i.Updated_Date
    ,i.IssueDate
    ,i.Historical
    ,i.Comments
    ,f.Current_status
    ,i.State as DocumentState
    ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY p.person_id) AS noOfRows
  from dbo.PersonDoc_ID_Numbers i
  inner join "DB"."dbo"."People" p on p.person_id = i.person_id
  left join person_facilities f on p.person_id = f.person_id
  where
  (Document like '%limited%' and i.State like '%NY%' and ((i.Expiration_date > getdate()) or (i.Expiration_date is null))) or 
  (Document like '%NY%' and i.State like '%NY%' and ((i.Expiration_date > getdate()) or (i.Expiration_date is null)))
  and f.current_status in ('Active') 
  and i.Historical != 1
)

SELECT Last_Name
  ,First_Name
  ,Middle_Initial
  ,person_id
  ,Document
  ,Expiration_date
  ,Updated_Date
  ,IssueDate
  ,Historical
  ,Comments
  ,Current_status
  ,DocumentState 
FROM myCte
WHERE noOfRows = 1
AND Document like '%limited%'
```

Here's a simplified example of this at work: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78e59/20)

**EDIT:**

Given the sample data you have provided, here is my suggested solution:

```
WITH myCte AS (
  SELECT
    p.Last,
    p.First,
    p.person_id,
    i.Document,
    i.Expiration_date,
    i.Updated_Date,
    i.Historical,
    f.Current_status,
    i.State as DocumentState,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY p.person_id) AS noOfRows
  FROM dbo.PersonDoc_ID_Numbers i
  JOIN dbo.Person p ON p.person_id = i.person_id
  JOIN person_facilities f ON p.person_id = f.person_id
  WHERE
    (Document like '%limited%' AND i.State like '%NY%' AND ((i.Expiration_date > getdate()) OR (i.Expiration_date is null))) or 
    (Document like '%NY%' AND i.State like '%NY%' AND ((i.Expiration_date > getdate()) OR (i.Expiration_date is null)))
    AND f.current_status in ('Active') 
    AND i.Historical != 1
)

SELECT Last
  ,First
  ,person_id
  ,Document
  ,Expiration_date
  ,Updated_Date
  ,Historical
  ,Current_status
  ,DocumentState 
FROM myCte
WHERE noOfRows = 1
AND Document like '%limited%'
```

Here's a new example using the data provided: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c4ea6/14)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure, it's not returning any rows.  I'll have to figure it out.

Comment: Any other ideas?  I was thinking maybe selecting for limited as one result, selecting for ny license as another result. Then left join the two things, and somehow pull out just the limited ones with no ny license? I'm really not sure.

Comment: @Michele I'm confident you can achieve what you want with my method. I used your original query, but it looks like it could be optimised. I can work on it further if you provide sample data for all three tables. CREATE and INSERT statements would be super!

Comment: I did a query that just pulls the limited ny ones.  Once I went through them one by one, I found that only 2 out of 5 were limited without the ny license too.  So it looks like both solutions aren't quite right since they have a null set returned instead of 2.  I can't provide create/insert statements though.  These tables are the back end of a larger application so we don't create/insert.  I can add example tables for all three though, in the original question.

Comment: @Michele What you have provided was all I was after! Try it now. As well as providing a solution based on your example data, I also corrected a typo in my original suggestion which was almost certainly breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.Last_Name
        , p.First_Name
        , p.Middle_Initial
        , p.person_id
        , i.Document
        , i.Expiration_date
        , i.Updated_Date
    FROM dbo.PersonDoc_ID_Numbers i
    JOIN "DB"."dbo"."People" p ON p.person_id = i.person_id
    JOIN person_facilities f ON p.person_id = f.person_id
    WHERE /*Document LIKE '%limited%' 
        AND i.State LIKE '%NY%' 
        AND*/ (i.Expiration_date > GETDATE() OR i.Expiration_date IS NULL)
        AND f.current_status IN ('Active') 
        AND i.Historical != 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c
WHERE Document LIKE '%limited%' AND i.State LIKE '%NY%' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM cte
        WHERE person_id = p.person_id AND Document NOT LIKE '%limited%' AND i.State LIKE '%NY%'
    )
ORDER BY Last_Name
```

Comment: IDK.  It's not returning anything under column headers.

Comment: It's still coming up with just headers